# xgboost TypeError: can not initialize DMatrix from DataFrame

Tags: xgboost

I am getting the below error when creating a DMatrix from a data in python.

> TypeError: can not initialize DMatrix from DataFrame
>   Exception AttributeError: "'DMatrix' object has no attribute 'handle'" in  <bound method DMatrix.__del__ ofrix object at 0x584d210>> ignored

Comment: Can you post the code from where you get this error?

Comment: Maybe because your DataFrame has categorical data.

Answer (score 1):

Without accompanying code my best guess is you are passing the pandas data-frame directly, instead you need to pass numpy representation of the dataframe 
 ie., pandas.DataFrame.values as below

```
X_train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
y_train = X_train['label']
X_train.drop(['label'],axis=1,inplace=True)
final_GBM.fit(X_train.values,y_train.values)
```